# iOS: Get localised hour from NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, localization, nsdateformatter

How to get localized hours only from NSDate respective to 12 hr/24 hr time is set by the user on device?
Consider date is "3 Jun 2015 3:00PM"
If 12 hour format is set then it should show 3PM (excluding minutes part)
If 24 hour format is set then it should show 15 (excluding minutes part)

I have tried with following without success on all locales. For example it is working perfect for de_DE & fr_FR but for en_US it always returns 3 without AM/PM.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
NSString *localeFormatString = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"HH" options:0 locale:dateFormatter.locale];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = localeFormatString;
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

NSString * hour = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",hour);
```

P.S.
If I get the time string (hours & minutes both) using following code, it works perfectly with respect to locale as well as 12/24 hour time format. However I want to get only hours and this is not achieved with 12/24 hour time format.

```
  NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  timeFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
  timeFormatter.dateFormat = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
  timeFormatter.AMSymbol = @"a";
  timeFormatter.PMSymbol = @"p";

  timeFormatter.timeZone = timeZone;
  return [timeFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack, but getting a localized hour string, such as "5 PM" or "17" (depending on the user's locale settings), can be achieved by:

1. Constructing an `NSDate` with the desired hour, and with the minute set to 0;
2. Using `NSDateFormatter` to get a localized string representation of that date using date style `NSDateFormatterNoStyle` and time style `NSDateFormatterShortStyle`;
3. Manually removing the `:00` from the string (if desired).

Code:

```
// Construct an NSDate whose hour is set to the specified hour, with minutes and seconds 0.
// (The date of the object is irrelevant, we won't use it.)
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setHour:hour];
[components setMinute:0];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *topOfHour = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

// Get a localized string representation of the time, e.g. "5:00 PM" or "17:00"
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
timeFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
timeFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
NSString *hourString = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:topOfHour];

// Remove the ":00" from the string.
hourString = [hourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":00" withString:@""];
```

If you want to remove the ":00" portion only from time strings that include an AM/PM indicator, to end up with strings like (e.g.) "5 PM" or "17:00", you can wrap that last line above in a conditional, like:

```
if ([hourString containsString:timeFormatter.AMSymbol] || [hourString containsString:timeFormatter.PMSymbol])
{
    hourString = [hourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":00" withString:@""];
}
```

Since this implementation relies on the hard-coded ":00", it might not work for some locales, e.g. locales which don't use `:` for the hours-minutes separator, or locales which don't count minutes starting at 0, or locales which also include the seconds in the `NSDateFormatterShortStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

You will be use NSDateFormatter with dd-MM-yyyy and then use NSTimeZone applied to the formatter  to adjust for the local time zone.

```
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", date);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSString *strDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"%@", strDateString);

NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
NSLog(@"adjusted for timezone: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: Thanks. however I don't need entire date string only hours, will try with your code with format "hh a".

Comment: This is not 12/24 hour format specific, it always returns hours with AM/PM. However it should not return AM/PM if time format is 24 hour.

Comment: used below code to convert am/pm
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];